# Having onFocus do several things

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this input tag `<input ... onFocus=...>` and what I want is for a warning popup to come up if somebody clicks to write in the input field. After the person has read the warning he/she closes the popup and can continue to write in the field. I have managed to implement the popup just fine but my problem is that I lose focus on the input field when the popup comes up so the next time I click the field the popup comes back again and im back on square one.

The system I work on uses php and javascript so and I cannot use anything other than that to solve the problem and my experience with both php and javascript is limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the onfocus run a function that checks via a variable if the alert has already been shown. I assume you don't want to show the alert more than once per page view, so something like this would work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var focusShown = false;

function showFocusAlert ()
{
    if (!focusShown)
    {
        alert("You are about to focus!");
        focusShown = true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Then use something like this in the input:

```
<input type="text" onfocus="showFocusAlert()" />
```

Comment: I think he means confirmation dialog, so something like this might be what he's after: `focusShown = confirm("Sure to edit this field?");`

Answer (score 0):

When you close the warning , you can put the focus on the input again.

See a demo http://jsbin.com/ifice4/

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to do with jQuery using the [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function:

```
$('#foo').one('focus', function() {
  alert('This will be displayed only once.');
});
```

The advantage of using jQuery or a javascript framework is that it makes it very easy for you to write unobtrusive javascript.